# How do I tie a note with other notes in between without creating a slur?

Tags: notation

For example, let's say I have four quarter notes, only I want to first note to span the length of all four, and I want the other three notes to be played individually with no slurring involved. Is there a way to write this in music notation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes--put the first note in a separate voice from the other 3, and make that first note a whole note instead.